# Query fails in multithreaded program while debugging with GDB

Tags: c++, mysql, c, gdb, mysql-connector

I tried to debug a program for some other errors and when running the program in multithreaded mode (more queries in the same time), queries start to fail/timeout:

> Lost connection to MySQL server during query

or

> MySQL has gone away

This does not happen while running single threaded with GDB or when running multithreaded without GDB.

What could be the issue, and how can it be fixed?

## Update

---

Also while trying to debug, running `print mysql_error(conn)` gives:

> The program received a signal in another thread while making a
>   function call from GDB. Evaluation of the expression containing the
>   function (mysql_error) will be abandoned. When the function is done
>   executing, GDB will silently stop.

Comment: What is the exact error message?

Comment: "Lost connection to MySQL server during query" "MySQL server has gone away" from `fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", mysql_error(conn));` after `mysql_real_query(conn, &query[0],query.size()) !=0 `

Comment: This may be because of max_allowed_packet

Change in the my.ini/my.cnf file. Include the single line under [mysqld] in your file

max_allowed_packet=500M
now restart the MySQL service once you are done. You can see it's curent value in mysql like this:

Comment: max_allowed_packet is 16MB, changing in a few minutes, have a procedure that is running now

Comment: Does this only occur when stepping through your code by hand, or also if just give gdb an initial "run" without breaking somehwere in your code? In the former case I suspect MySQLjust timing out, while gdb had stopped because of having reached a break-point.

Comment: Just running. There is a breakpoint before program finish, but that's not reached.